# How would you concatenate "on the fly" a text+integer passing it to a function?

Tags: c++, string, concatenation

I've a function in a library (so, that I cannot change) like this:

```
char mName[MAX_PARAM_NAME_LEN];

void IParam::InitBool(const char* name) {
    strcpy(mName, name);
}
```

I'd like to pass text as `Text0`, `Text1` (and so on) "faster", writing directly inside the function, starting from a text and an integer, without store additional variables on my own; such as:

```
int mIndex = 0;
InitBool("Text" + mIndex);
```

How would you do it? Wrap functions? Which one? Best approch? In `C#` thats pretty done, I find hard to do it in `C++`.

Comment: @Öö Tiib: no! I'm asking how to do it "on the fly", without using vars.

Comment: `InitBool(("Text" + std::to_string(mIndex)).c_str());` ?

Comment: @markzzz yes! most of the answers to that question were how to do it on the fly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++ `"Text"` is a `const char[N]`, it's not actually a string type but just an array of characters with a null character (`'\0'`) at the end.  This doesn't support any sort of string manipulation.  What you need to get is a `std::string`, which does support many string operations.  Since you need to convert `mIndex` to a string to begin with we can just to that and the string that represents the number will handle concatenating `"Text"` to it.  That gives you

```
int mIndex = 0;
InitBool(("Text" + std::to_string(mIndex)).c_str());
```

The `("Text" + std::to_string(mIndex))` part gives you a temporary `std::string` that is `"Text0"` and then the `.c_str()` gets a `const char*` to that string to pass to the function.

---

You can wrap the `("Text" + std::to_string(mIndex))` part in a function like

```
std::string concat(const char* str, int val)
{
    return str + std::to_string(val);
}
```

and then the function call would look like

```
InitBool(concat("Text", mIndex).c_str());
```

Comment: How would you wrap it to a function? So I can call it to `Concat("Text", mIndex)`?

Comment: @markzzz you do not, you would get dangling pointer. You better use `std::string` instead of char array.

Comment: @markzzz I would just use `("Text" + std::to_string(mIndex)).c_str()` at the call site.  Trying to wrap this in a function will be painful.  You could make a macro, but I dislike that in this case.

Comment: Or `InitBool(Concat("Text", mIndex).c_str())`.

Comment: Possibly: `InitBool(param, "Text", m_Index)` with `template <typename ...Ts> void InitBool(IParam&, Ts&&...)`.

Comment: Tried somethings like this but its a pain: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/79d2f918e04948dc

Comment: @markzz but you did not ask how to write a function that concatenates string and number but "no! I'm asking how to do it "on the fly", without using vars."

Comment: @markzzz I've updated the answer to wrap it in a function.

Comment: @Jarod42 Good suggestion.  I've added that to the answer.

Comment: @markzzz: your method return dangling pointer.

Comment: @NathanOliver so the memory allocated by the returned `std::string` will be cleaned up once exited from `InitBool` right?

Comment: lifetime of that temporary ends at the end of full expression and so is valid inside `InitBool`. But in your sample, it ends at the end of full expression of `return`, so before `InitBool`.

Comment: @markzzz Yes.  The memory from the string returned by `concat` will be cleaned up after `InitBool` ends.

Comment: @Jarod42: return? I mean the temporany var returned by that function, which is passed to InitBool. When will die it?

Comment: Your way is invalid (`const char* concat(const char*, int)`) whereas proposed solution is valid: `std::string concat(const char*, int)`. You can still create dangling pointer with `const char* dangling = concat("t", 42).c_str();` but `InitBool(concat("t", 42).c_str())` is fine.

Answer (score 3):

If your compiler supports C++17 features you could use a [fold expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) and string stream. The magic happens in the `stringify()` function which accepts zero or more arguments.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

template <typename... Ts>
std::string stringify(const Ts&... args)
{
    std::ostringstream oss;
    (oss << ... << args);
    return oss.str();
}

void InitBool(const char *name)
{
    std::cout << name << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    int mIndex = 0;

    InitBool(stringify("Text", mIndex, '!', 1.0/3.0).c_str());
}
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/140608a9e9d9aa3f)

Comment: A bit modification to your code and [here is the C++11 solution](https://wandbox.org/permlink/bMbVSTiCgZba2yOf)  so that OP can work with. ;)

Comment: @JeJo That looks good, you might want to post that as an answer.

Comment: No... Since the idea is your, I would like to see in your answer. ;) You can update with.  Also keep in mind that OP might need to clear the global ostringstream for the next time `InitBool()` call.